# Zencode pattern not found

Tags: reactjs, encryption, cryptography, zenroom

I am trying to make a platform that uses zero knowledge proof, and i need to create a credential key using zenroom, I am using the contract in [apiroom](https://apiroom.net/) and the contracts works, but when i use it in the react page it give this error

```json
{
    "result": "",
    "logs": " .  System memory manager in use\n .  MUTT print functions in use\n .  ECDH curve is SECP256K1\n .  Memory in use: 301 KB\n[W]  .  Scenario credential[!] Zencode execution error\n[!] Script:\nZEN:begin()\nZEN:parse([[\nScenario credential: credential keygen\nGiven my name is in a 'string' named 'userId'\nWhen I create the credential key\nThen print my 'keys'\n]])\nZEN:run()\n\n[!] /zenroom_ast.lua:83: Zencode pattern not found: When I create the credential key\n[!] Error detected. Execution aborted.\n[*] Zenroom teardown.\n .  Memory used: 353 KB\n"
}
```

this is the contract code

```
Scenario credential: credential keygen
Given my name is in a 'string' named 'userId'
When I create the credential key
Then print my 'keys'
```

I am using zenroom version ^2.2.0
and react vesion ^17.0.2

Answer (score 1):

i find the answer the next day but i forgot to post it here, the fix was just using this exact version of zenroom 2.2.0-d7bdfb4d